# How to extract links behind a text tag of web page (using either curl,wget or userscript)

Tags: bash, curl, userscripts

I'm trying to extract href links under tag. 
Refer to the attachment. I want to save all link under the tag "PDF".
`http://tinypic.com/r/2n9erdj/8` Sorry I'm not allowed update pictures as yet.

Specifically the href details appear as arnumber=60940cc as shown in red circle.

Can someone suggest how to implement this. I'm intending to use either a userscript or bash commands.

html elements details relavant to a single pdf is shown below.

```
<a aria-label="Download or View the PDF:  IEEE Transactions on Power Electronics publication information" href="/stampPDF/getPDF.jsp?tp=&amp;arnumber=6094072"><img class="button" src="http://staticieeexplore.ieee.org/assets/img/iconPdf.png" alt="PDF file icon" title="Download or View the PDF">PDF</a>
```

The web page I'm testing is

> http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/tocresult.jsp?isnumber=6088512

The objective is to filter the content named as "pdf" and its urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Tweak sed part if you don't want "http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/" just before stamp word or etc

```
wget http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/tocresult.jsp?isnumber=6088512 -O file.html
grep -o "href.*stamp.*\"><" file.html |sed 's#"#"http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org#;s#><##'

href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6094070"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6094072"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6094110"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6088513"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5680978"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5985544"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5723758"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5716681"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5936741"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5934597"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5734858"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5756244"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5759746"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5958614"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5999721"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6021380"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5961632"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5951783"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5983448"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5934423"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5957306"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5898425"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5959991"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5776690"
href="http://ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5953525"
```

OR

```
$ grep -o "href.*stamp.*\"><" file.html |sed 's#href="#ieeexplorer.ieee.org#;s#"><##'

ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6094070
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6094072
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6094110
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6088513
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5680978
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5985544
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5723758
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5716681
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5936741
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5934597
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5734858
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5756244
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5759746
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5958614
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5999721
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6021380
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5961632
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5951783
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5983448
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5934423
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5957306
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5898425
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5959991
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5776690
ieeexplorer.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5953525
```

Comment: Thanks is works. How can i modify it to following format. ieeexplore.ieee.org/stampPDF/getPDF.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6094070   and save the output list into a a text file journalpapers.txt    (sorry I'm quite new to linux)